# How can I achieve this continuous gradient effect?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Any tips on how to achieve this continuous gradient throughout a shape? I've had luck creating this shape by using the Blend Tool between two circles in Illustrator, and then duplicating them, but I can't figure out how to move across one gradient to another, then another, then another. Any help is appreciated.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had success at this using the **Blend tool** but creating your gradient on the **stroke** instead of the fill. Also use a very high number of blend steps like 400 or so. I hope this helps.